# Why does the constant of integration always come with the independent variable whilst integrating differential equations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

Say, we had the following differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}x = 1+y$$

When we re-arrange the equation and integrate both sides, why will the constant of integration ONLY come with the independent variable, $x$?

My assumption is that it's because we can think of a function as having an input and an output. The output is the dependent variable, and input is the independent variable. So, all the work is done on the input, to get a desired output. So, the constant should only come with the independent variable. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's an arbitrary constant. You can put it wherever you want. If you end up with a constant on both sides, you can combine them into a single constant.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what side of the equation we put it on. Observe

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}x=y+1$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y+1}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y+1}=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$

$$\ln{\left(y+1\right)}+C_y=\ln{x}+C_x$$

Now, here is the reason it doesn't matter: just bring both constants over to either side

$$\ln{\left(y+1\right)}+\left(C_y-C_x\right)=\ln{x}$$

$$\left(y+1\right)\,\mathrm{e}^{C_y-C_x}=x$$

If we want $y$ in terms of $x$, then we can rearrange to get

$$y=x\,\mathrm{e}^{C_x-C_y}-1$$

But, you ask, aren't there two constants now? No, the expression $\mathrm{e}^{C_x-C_y}$ acts as a single constant. If you include an initial condition, then you would solve for this entire expression to get the final solution.

Comment: Ah, okay! I understand, thanks a bunch :D!

Comment: Minor comment: typically we treat the entire $e^{C_x - C_y}$ as just an arbitrary constant $C$. The fact that the exponential is always positive is counteracted by the absolute value signs in the integral of $\dfrac{1}{x}$, which is technically $\ln|x|$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Shouldn't that depend on the type of domain we're dealing with?

Comment: I don't think so, is there a particular reason you think it should?

Comment: I mean, if we're dealing with the complex plane then, the exponential functions can be negative, right?

Comment: True, but in the complex plane there is no absolute value inside the natural log when you take the integral, so you actually arrive at the same conclusion. My point was that the removal of the absolute value bars justifies changing the exponential to an arbitrary constant without the restriction that it needs to be positive. Does that help clear that up at all?

Comment: Hm, I had one problem. I don't understand HOW it justifies that the exponential can now (possibly) be negative? I mean, so far, I only know that ln(x) is only defined for x>0.

Comment: I get we're trying to justify that, since constants can be negative as well, the exponential function can be negative too. But the HOW, I don't get.

Comment: I think when I write it out it should make more sense: We start with $\ln|y+1| + (C_y-C_x) = \ln|x|$. Now take $e$ to the power of both sides: $|y+1|e^{C_y-C_x} = |x|$, and bringing the exponential to the right yields $|y+1|=|x|e^{C_y-C_x}$. Our calculation so far depends on $x \neq 0$ so we can divide by $|x|$ on both sides and use the linearity of absolute values to get $|\dfrac{y+1}{x}| = e^{C_y-C_x}$. This means that $\dfrac{y+1}{x} = \pm e^{C_y-C_x}$. Now define $C = \pm e^{C_y-C_x}$ and we have that $y = Cx - 1$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118006/discussion-between-ihateelectricalphysics-and-stephen-donovan).